# Apostrophes are being saved as &#039; using Gravity Forms on Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

I am using Gravity Forms (Wordpress) and when saving words with apostrophes, it saves it like that: '

**Example:**
today&amp;#039;s needs

How to to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you'd need to run the string value through an "html entity decode" function. And run the return from that back through through "html entity decode" again, to get back to the quote.

Comment: That's probably caused by the sanitization of the string

Comment: @Asur "That's probably caused by the sanitization of the string"... in the wrong place. You should never make assumptions about how the data will be used when saving it - only when using/displaying it.

Comment: @Dezza Ok, sorry that was just an idea I was thinking about because I had a similar case some time ago. Anyway, I'm sure that Gravity forms uses WP Sanitization API, but with that ammount of info is there anything else I can do beside assumptions?

Comment: @Asur It is a fair idea - I just wanted to add a bit to the end in case other people thought it was a good idea to try that themselves :)

Comment: I fixed it by wrapping the $value (used by Gravity Forms) with html_entity_decode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gravity Forms plugin fields files 
(wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/includes/fields) find $value and wrap it with  html_entity_decode()

```
$value = html_entity_decode($value);
```